# In windowsphone converting current time into millisecond

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have a time format like  this:

```
 string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

which gives me output like

```
11/29/2013 6:26:13PM
```

Now how can i convert this output into millisecond in windowsPhone???

Updated:
First i want to save the current time when the user launch my app.  after that whenever the user launch  my app again then i also get the time and compare the current launching  time with previously stored time and check whether the time difference becomes "one day" or not.
For this comparison i need to covert `11/29/2013 6:26:13PM` this into millisecond.

Another question tell me how can i convert "6:26:13PM" only this into millisecond??

Comment: so you want format of to display millisecond like 11/29/2013 6:26:13.ooo

Comment: Do you mean milliseconds since EPOC? Or current millisecond value for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly just do this:

Create a date from your input:

```
DateTime yourInitialDateTime = DateTime.Parse("11/29/2013 6:26:13PM");
```

After that

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - yourInitialDateTime;
```

So in `span.TotalDays` you will have how many days has passed.

**Edit**

If you have only the time of day and want to know the millisecond of that time you must add a date and subtract it with hour 0:00:00 like this:

```
string dummyDate = "01/01/0001";
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(dummyDate + " " + "6:26:13PM");
var milli = end.Subtract(new DateTime()).TotalMilliseconds;
```

That is it.

Comment: TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - yourInitialDateTime..In this line shows that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.TimeSpan'"  @Vitor Canova

Comment: So in Windows Phone `DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now` returns an `int` instead of `TimeSpan`? You sure? Maybe try `DateTime.Now.Subtract(yourInitialDateTime)` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: could u tell me how can i convert "6:26:13PM" only this into millisecond??

Comment: Sure.First Parse like code above and after `DateTime.Now.Subtract(yourInitialDateTime).TotalMilliseconds`. Remember to use `TotalMilliseconds` and no just `Milliseconds`.

Comment: Not previous code. I get time of a day using "myCurrentTime.TimeOfDay". Say i hv 2 time like 6:26:13PM and another is 5:6:19AM. Now how can i convert these 2 time into their respective millisecond ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```csharp
var ThatDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); //This is hard coded but you have to get from where you are storing.
var Today = DateTime.Now;

var Diff = (Today - ThatDay).Milliseconds;
var FriendlyDiff = (Today - ThatDay).ToFriendlyDisplay(5);
```

---

```csharp
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    private enum TimeSpanElement
    {
        Millisecond,
        Second,
        Minute,
        Hour,
        Day
    }

    public static string ToFriendlyDisplay(this TimeSpan timeSpan, int maxNrOfElements)
    {
        maxNrOfElements = Math.Max(Math.Min(maxNrOfElements, 5), 1);
        var parts = new[]
                    {
                        Tuple.Create(TimeSpanElement.Day, timeSpan.Days),
                        Tuple.Create(TimeSpanElement.Hour, timeSpan.Hours),
                        Tuple.Create(TimeSpanElement.Minute, timeSpan.Minutes),
                        Tuple.Create(TimeSpanElement.Second, timeSpan.Seconds),
                        Tuple.Create(TimeSpanElement.Millisecond, timeSpan.Milliseconds)
                    }
                                    .SkipWhile(i => i.Item2 <= 0)
                                    .Take(maxNrOfElements);

        return string.Join(", ", parts.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1}{2}", p.Item2, p.Item1, p.Item2 > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty)));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems too much complex to me. Isn't there any simple way?? @Xyroid

Comment: If you want only milliseconds then ignore ToFriendlyDisplay() method. `(Today - ThatDay)` with give you object of type `TimeSpan` which has individual properties of day, hour, minutes, etc. `TimeSpanExtensions` shows you time in friendly display.